# Cannot send hashed data through ManageDataOperation

Tags: java-sdk

I am trying to send a data hashed using SCryptUtil provided by com.lambdaworks.crypto.SCryptUtil, convert it into array of bytes and send it to the stellar network using ManageDataOperation.Builder

My code is as follows

```
        String hash = SCryptUtil.scrypt("HashData", 16384, 8, 1);

        byte[] hashByte = hash.getBytes();

        ManageDataOperation.Builder updateHashedData = new ManageDataOperation.Builder("Hashed Data", hashByte);

        Transaction tt = new Transaction.Builder(sourceAccount)
                        .addOperation(updateHashedData.build())
                        .addMemo(Memo.text("Test 
                        Transaction")).setTimeout(1000).build();
```

The data is not sent to the server. But when I use a simple string for the "hash" variable like "Password", it gets sent. What am I missing here? Is there a way to send long hashcodes to stellar account in this way?

Comment: I don't understand the example. You declare `hash`, assign it to `hashedData`, but you don't use that variable after that. You use the bytes from a new variable, `hashedPass` in the builder call. Where does `hashedPass` get set? What's in it?

Comment: Hi, sorry I made some adjustments in the code. Now it is correct.

Comment: How long (in bytes) is `hashByte`?

Comment: It's length is 150.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `ManageDataOperation` is limited in length (`hashByte.length <= 64`), if the length is exceeded, the submission will fail.

Comment: Thank You! So if I want to store data larger than that, I should be storing them off the chain?

Comment: You can store the data off the chain and store the hash of the file on Stellar, another option is to store the file on IPFS and then save the hash on Stellar. I hope this [article](https://hackernoon.com/building-an-app-with-stellar-and-ipfs-7ad57b48fda5) can help you.

Comment: Relevant doc: https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#manage-data